# Set print quality to ‘Best’ by default

Tags: macos, printing

When printing in macOS, I can set the print quality in the **Media & Quality** section:

[image: macOS print dialog]

Is it possible to set the quality setting to ‘Best’ by default? It’s a bit annoying to change it every time (because I prefer to use ‘Best’ for most of my prints).

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Gummibando Sorry for the delay! I did, and it works great :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your settings and then save them as a custom preset in the *Presets* drop-down (*Save Current Settings as Preset…*).

After selecting your preset and printing once, the preset is remembered in all applications that use the standard print dialog.

Just make sure the *Reset Presets Menu to "Default Settings" After Printing* checkbox is unchecked in the Presets window/dialog (*Show Presets…* in the drop-down), which it should be by default.

[image]
[image]